# How to implement phone number verification in flutter using firebase? (Not Authentication)

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication, phone-number

how to implement phone number verification in flutter using firebase?. my app need to verify the phone number at a point of time. not needed authentication by phone number. I just need to verify my number. How I implement that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Firebase phone number verification automatically also authenticates the user. There is no way to verify a user's phone number with Firebase Authentication without signing the user in.

Comment: can you suggest third-party plugins for phone number verification

Comment: Such recommendations are off-topic on Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and discussion. But a Google search is likely to give you good options.

Comment: If I have already created an account for a user, and then implement phone authentication (user is already signed in), will it create a new user account? Or will this work to verify the phone number and it just happens to log them in (even though they are are in already). Another way of asking, is it possible to have them be able authenticate via phone in addition to email/pwd?

Answer (score 3):

It's true in firebase you can't just verify a phone number and that a phone number verification automatically authenticates the user but that's  okay. You can link a phone number to an already authenticated user. Linking the phone number means that the user can log in with their already existing provider (gmail, Facebook, email, etc) as well as log in with their phone number and use the same password for their account.

See sample flutter code

```
_verifyPhoneNumber() async {
    await FirebaseAuth.instance.verifyPhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: '+44 7123 123 456',
    verificationCompleted: (PhoneAuthCredential credential) {
     // For andriod only automatic handling of the SMS code
    },
    verificationFailed: (FirebaseAuthException e) {},
    codeSent: (String verificationId, int? resendToken) {
      // SMS Code sent show a dialogue to enter the code.
     _displayPhoneNumberVerificationDialog(verificationId);
    },
    codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: (String verificationId) {},
  );
}
```

Inside `_displayPhoneNumberVerificationDialog(verificationId)` have a dialogue with a submit button. The linking logic will be onTap of the button.

Sample _displayPhoneNumberVerificationDialog

```
_displayPhoneNumberVerificationDialogSt(String verificationId) {
      FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth = firebase.FirebaseAuth.instance;
      return showDialog(
          context: context,
          builder: (context) {
            return AlertDialog(
              title: Text('Enter verification code'),
              content: TextField(
                keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                textInputAction: TextInputAction.done,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "phone number"),
                onChanged: (input) {
                  _smsVerificationCode = input;
                },
              ),
              actions: <Widget>[
                new FlatButton(
                  child: new Text('Submit'),
                  onPressed: () async {
                    Navigator.of(context).pop();
                    // Create a PhoneAuthCredential with the code
                    PhoneAuthCredential credential;
                    try {
                      credential = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
                          verificationId: verificationId,
                          smsCode: _smsVerificationCode);
                    } catch (e) {
                      // Show Error usually wrong _smsVerfication code entered
                      return;
                    }
                    User currentUser = await firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    try {
                      // This try catch helps if you want to update an existing verified phone number and you want to verify the new one.
                      // We unlink the old phone number so a new one can be linked
                      // This is not relevant if you're just going to verify and link a phone number without updating it later.
                      currentUser = await currentUser.unlink("phone");
                    } catch (e) {
                      print(e);
                      currentUser = await firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
                    }
                    try {
                      currentUser.linkWithCredential(credential).then((value) {
                        // Verfied now perform something or exit.
                      }).catchError((e) {
                        // An error occured while linking
                      });
                    } catch (e) {
                      // General error
                    }
                  },
                )
              ],
            );
          });
    }
```

Helpful doc: https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/auth/phone/

Answer (score 1):

do it manually , using [PhoneNumberUtil](https://pub.dev/documentation/libphonenumber/latest/libphonenumber/PhoneNumberUtil-class.html) class  and a manual method in code to verify on the country codes

The method checks for the country codes of the number in this case i specify only allow Kenyan Numbers with the country code 'KE'

```
 _checkPhoneNumber() async {
var s = phoneTextFieldController.text;
bool isValid;
if (s.length == 0) {
  isValid = true;
  setState(() {
    _isPhoneNumber = isValid;
  });
  return;
}
 //check if the number starts with '0' , or '07' or '254'
if (s.length < 10) {
  isValid = s.length == 1 && s[0] == '0' ||
      s.length > 1 && s[0] + s[1] == '07' ||
      s.length > 1 && s[0] + s[1] + s[2] == '254' ||
      s.length > 1 && s[0] + s[1] + s[2] + s[3] == '+254';
  setState(() {
    _isPhoneNumber = isValid;
  });

  return;
}

isValid =
    await PhoneNumberUtil.isValidPhoneNumber(phoneNumber: s, isoCode: 'KE');
String normalizedNumber = await PhoneNumberUtil.normalizePhoneNumber(
    phoneNumber: s, isoCode: 'KE');
RegionInfo regionInfo =
    await PhoneNumberUtil.getRegionInfo(phoneNumber: s, isoCode: 'KE');

setState(() {
  _isPhoneNumber = isValid;
});
}
```

Then in your form have

```
child: TextFormField(
                          onChanged: (text) {
                            _checkPhoneNumber();
                          },
                          controller: phoneTextFieldController,
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,

                          validator: (val) {
                            if (val == '') {
                              return 'Phone Number is required';
                            }
                            if (!_isPhoneNumber) {
                              return 'Phone Number format error';
                            }
                          },
                          decoration: InputDecoration(
                              hintText: "2547xx xxx xxx - Phone",
                              border: InputBorder.none,
                              icon: const Icon(
                                Icons.phone,
                              ),
                              labelText: 'Phone',
                              prefixText: '     ',
                              suffixStyle:
                                  const TextStyle(color: Colors.green)),
                          onSaved: (value) {
                            phoneNumberForm = value;
                          },
                        )),
```

Then on form submit check the form state

```
 buttonCustom(
                  color: Color(0xFF4458be),
                  heigth: 50.0,
                  txt: contactIdParam!=null ?"Submit Edit":"Submit",
                  ontap: () {
                    final _form = form.currentState;
                    if (_form.validate()) {
                      if(contactIdParam!=null){
                         _editContactRequest();
                      }else{
                        _addContactRequest();

                      }

                    } else {
                      print('form is invalid');
                    }
                  },
                ),
```

Nb: have copied snippets form my working code my validation will differ from what you want but what you need is just the logic